# Highcharts: legend on bottom with custom marginBottom already

Tags: highcharts

When a legend is placed under the chart, the bottom margin is usually determined automatically so that everything fits well.

But I have a chart which includes some custom stuff in the bottom margin, and hence I've had to override `marginBottom`.  This messes with the automatic calculation when a legend is also placed under the chart.

I've done a simple mockup in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fauh2bk/3/), where you can enable / disable the legend and change the number of series, to see how things look messed up.

I'm guessing that I probably have to make the necessary adjustments to `marginBottom` myself to account for the legend, but how?

Any idea how I might do this?

EDIT: I think I'm getting close... but I'm not sure if I'm going about it the best way... see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fauh2bk/4/).

Comment: What you have in the second fiddle seems pretty sound from what I can see. I have a similar situation with some of my own charts, and what you built will be immensely helpful for me. Please note that your adjustments are breaking the native responsiveness of the chart (I'm not quite sure why, and this may not be a dealbreaker for you).

Comment: @brightmatrix what aspect of the native responsiveness is broken?

Comment: When you resize the window in your fiddle that contains the chart, it should automatically adjust to fit its contents. Compare your fiddle vs. the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/.

Comment: Ah OK.  For my purposes that isn't an issue, but it would be nice to find a solution without that flaw.

Answer (score 1):

I've been mulling over this question and your updated fiddle for a few weeks now, and I think I've solved both your initial issue and the responsive bug that I brought up in the comments.

In your `chart` option, I added a load event that pulls in the series at render time, vs. the appended function you used after the options. I also removed the explicit `marginBottom` declaration.

```
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        borderWidth: 1,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        events: {
            load: function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSeries; i++) this.addSeries(basicSeries);
          }
        }
    },
```

What this does is pull in the number of series (which you've declared as a static variable at the top of your code) and add them at runtime. Highcharts' code will then automatically adjust the needed space under your chart to accommodate the size of the legend and its items.

Here's an updated version of your (updated) fiddle with these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/4fauh2bk/6/

**A sidenote:** What broke the responsive nature of the chart was the fixed width value in the `chart.setSize()` function. It seems like setting a width of `auto` or a percentage (such as `100%`) will keep its ability to resize, but the chart may need to be redrawn after you execute the function.